# Flexbox bug in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: flexbox, internet-explorer-11, grid-layout

I'm having some problems in Internet Explorer 11 with a flexbox grid on this page: http://showit.magnetix.dk/jeppe/sdc-academy/

The section `.modules-overview` works as wanted, but the `.news` section (in the top) doesn't. However, the CSS used in very similar, so I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Normally I would post useful code here, but since this is a flexbox bug specific for IE11 I felt it was better to post the link above.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding.

```
.news__item {
     flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```